# Adding image from gallery and saving to pdf in adroid studio

Tags: android, pdf, imageview, itext

I made an app in android studio (Java) on which is possible to fill some brief data in text boxes. Also app has two buttons, one for loading image from gallery and one for saving complete data to pdf. 
I can successfully save all text data, but have problem with loaded image. Image is sucessfully loaded to app, but i dont know hot to save it to pdf. Image is loaded as an ImageView object.
Just to mention for pdf part i use itext.

Pls, help with hints or code for saving ImageVIew object to pdf file.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem, but i can fixed.
first i changed the way i used to pick the image and replaced it with this code:

```
    Intent getImage = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(getImage, GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

then, in the class onActivityResult i transformed the uri to a bitmap using this:

```
     if(requestCode==GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode== RESULT_OK && data!=null){
        Uri imageData = data.getData();
        String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(imageData,filePath,null,null,null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
        String myPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(myPath);
```

then passed the bitmap to the pdf

```
    pdf.addFoto(bitmap);
```

and finally, in the pdf template i used this to put the image in a table:

```
    public void addFoto (Bitmap u) {
    try{
        PdfPTable tabla = new PdfPTable(1);
        tabla.setWidthPercentage(60);
        tabla.setSpacingBefore(10);
        tabla.setSpacingAfter(10);

        Bitmap bmp = u;
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        Image image = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());

        PdfPCell imageCell = new PdfPCell();
        imageCell.addElement(image);
        tabla.addCell(imageCell);
        document.add(tabla);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into [PdfDocument](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument)

Example from the documentation

```
  // create a new document
 PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();

 // crate a page description
 PageInfo pageInfo = new PageInfo.Builder(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100), 1).create();

 // start a page
 Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);

 // draw something on the page
 View content = getContentView();
 content.draw(page.getCanvas());

 // finish the page
 document.finishPage(page);
 . . .
 // add more pages
 . . .
 // write the document content
 document.writeTo(getOutputStream());

 // close the document
 document.close();
```

Comment: i dont see here how you can incorporate ImageVIew object